# React TypeScript: Component Slots with Type-Safety

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a working example of a component API I'm trying to achieve. However I'm not able to properly get type-safety for the children and className prop. Here's my component:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";
import {
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef,
  ElementType,
  PropsWithChildren,
} from "react";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

const Variants = cva(
  "relative inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-black/30 dark:bg-white/30 backdrop-blur-lg",
  {
    variants: {
      size: {
        xs: "w-6 h-6",
        sm: "w-8 h-8",
        md: "w-10 h-10",
        lg: "w-12 h-12",
        xl: "w-14 h-14",
        "2xl": "w-16 h-16",
      },
      shape: {
        square: "rounded-none",
        rounded: "rounded-md",
        circular: "rounded-full",
      },
    },
  }
);

export type Slot<T extends ElementType = ElementType> =
  T extends infer U extends string ? U : T;

export type ComponentWithSlots<
  P,
  S extends Record<string, Slot>
> = PropsWithChildren<
  P & {
    slots?: { [K in keyof S]?: ElementType };
    slotProps?: { [K in keyof S]?: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<S[K]> };
  }
> &
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<S["root"]>;

export interface AvatarProps {
  src?: string;
  alt?: string;
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "2xl";
  shape?: "square" | "rounded" | "circular";
}

export type AvatarSlots = {
  root: Slot<"div">;
  image: Slot<"img">;
};

export function Avatar<T extends AvatarSlots = AvatarSlots>({
  className,
  children,
  src,
  alt = "Avatar",
  size = "md",
  shape = "circular",
  slots,
  slotProps,
  ...props
}: ComponentWithSlots<AvatarProps, T>) {
  const Root = slots?.root ?? "div";
  const Image = slots?.image ?? "img";

  const rootClassNames = twMerge(Variants({ size, shape }), className);
  const imageClassNames = twMerge(
    "h-full w-full object-cover",
    slotProps?.image?.className
  );

  return (
    <Root {...props} {...slotProps?.root} className={rootClassNames}>
      {src ? (
        <Image
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
          {...slotProps?.image}
          className={imageClassNames}
        />
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Root>
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <Avatar
        src="/favicon.ico"
        alt="Logo"
        size="2xl"
        slots={{ image: Image }}
        slotProps={{ image: { layout: "fill" } }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

I want to merge the props of the 'Slot' that gets inferred, this can be any HTML element.What might be the best approach for this?

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-cloud-tw4vc7?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A43%2C1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve what you're trying to do -

```ts
import Image from "next/image";
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";
import {
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef,
  ElementType,
  PropsWithChildren,
} from "react";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

const Variants = cva(
  "relative inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-black/30 dark:bg-white/30 backdrop-blur-lg",
  {
    variants: {
      size: {
        xs: "w-6 h-6",
        sm: "w-8 h-8",
        md: "w-10 h-10",
        lg: "w-12 h-12",
        xl: "w-14 h-14",
        "2xl": "w-16 h-16",
      },
      shape: {
        square: "rounded-none",
        rounded: "rounded-md",
        circular: "rounded-full",
      },
    },
  }
);

export type Slot<T extends ElementType = ElementType> =
  T extends infer U extends string ? U : T;

export type ComponentWithSlots<
  P,
  S extends Record<string, Slot>
> = PropsWithChildren<
  P & {
    // Change from ElementType to S[K]
    slots?: { [K in keyof S]?: S[K] };
    slotProps?: {
      // Omit the AvatarProps from the slot
      [K in keyof S]?: Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<S[K]>, keyof Required<P>>;
    };
  }
> &
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<S["root"]>;

// I don't think src, and alt should be optional
export interface AvatarProps {
  src?: string;
  alt?: string;
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "2xl";
  shape?: "square" | "rounded" | "circular";
}

// Make AvatarSlots generic
export type AvatarSlots<R extends ElementType, I extends ElementType> = {
  root: Slot<R>;
  image: Slot<I>;
};

// Add generics correctly to be able to infer from the return type
export function Avatar<
  RootEl extends ElementType = "div",
  ImgEl extends ElementType = "img"
>({
  className,
  children,
  src,
  alt = "Avatar",
  size = "md",
  shape = "circular",
  slots,
  slotProps,
  ...props
}: ComponentWithSlots<AvatarProps, AvatarSlots<RootEl, ImgEl>>) {
  const Root = slots?.root ?? "div";
  const Image = slots?.image ?? "img";

  const rootClassNames = twMerge(Variants({ size, shape }), className);
  const imageClassNames = twMerge(
    "h-full w-full object-cover",
    slotProps?.image?.className
  );

  return (
    <Root {...props} {...slotProps?.root} className={rootClassNames}>
      {src ? (
        <Image
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
          {...slotProps?.image}
          className={imageClassNames}
        />
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Root>
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <Avatar
        src="/favicon.ico"
        alt="Logo"
        size="2xl"
        slots={{ image: Image }}
        slotProps={{ image: { layout: "fill" } }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/amazing-wu-rcsms4).

**NOTE**: Since you've added the `src` and `alt` props in the `Avatar` component, I'd to make an adjustment while inferring the props from the `slot`, in particular, the `Image` component that you're using has a required prop of `src` and `alt`, so I'd to `Omit` the `AvatarProps` from the props of whatever slot that's chosen, and that's how it should be actually. One shouldn't be prompted to provide `src` and `alt` in the `slotProps`. My recommendation is to make `src` and `alt` required in `AvatarProps`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the type definition:

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

export function Avatar<T extends Record<string, Slot> = AvatarSlots>({
  className,
  children,
  src,
  alt = "Avatar",
  size = "md",
  shape = "circular",
  slots,
  slotProps,
  ...props
  // add this:
}: PropsWithChildren<ComponentWithSlots<AvatarProps, T>> & {
  className?: string;
}) {
  const Root = slots?.root ?? "div";
  const Image = slots?.image ?? "img";

  const rootClassNames = twMerge(Variants({ size, shape }), className);
  const imageClassNames = twMerge(
    "h-full w-full object-cover",
    slotProps?.image?.className
  );

  return (
    <Root {...props} {...slotProps?.root} className={rootClassNames}>
      {src ? (
        <Image
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
          {...slotProps?.image}
          className={imageClassNames}
        />
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Root>
  );
}
```

You can also extract it to a separate type alias.

Comment: So ideally I want the actual ...props destructure to match the HTML element props that get set. For ex: my AvatarSlots type declares 'root' as a "div" element. Ideally, if no slot is passed by the user then the props should be ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div"> by default, and ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> where T is the component type passed in by the user for the root slot. I didn't want to manually add children and className as those are usually part of the HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> types which Id want to be inferred from the the default slot types.

Comment: I've update my example to allow any ElementType as a slot rather than constraining it in the type. However, I'm facing one final issue where slotProps is inferred incorrectly.